# Fallthrough issue in Javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, fall-through

I have a large array of features with p and u properties. I want to find the smallest and highest p and u in the array and create this switch statement in a loop. This works about 99.9% of the time. However. I have one data set where the max and min turn out to be the same even if the values are evenly distributed and the average is not the same. Stumped.

```
            switch(true) {
                case p > max_p:
                    max_p = p;
                case u > max_u:
                    max_u = u;
                case p < min_p:
                    min_p = p;
                case u < min_u:
                    min_u = u;
            }
```

I run through the loop in firebug and can see that max_u gets sometimes updated if u < max_u. For example u = 0.066, max_u = 0.088.

Pycharm tells me about a fallthrough issue but the statement works fine on every other dataset I throw at it.

I can split the statement into two. The performance loss is minor but I would like to understand how this could happen.

Thanks,
Dennis

edit:

Split into two statement that dataset works completely fine without a break in the statement.

```
            switch(true) {
                case p > max_p:
                    max_p = p;
                case p < min_p:
                    min_p = p;
            }
            switch(true) {
                case u > max_u:
                    max_u = u;
                case u < min_u:
                    min_u = u;
            }
```

edit: I accepted the answer given which works but I am still puzzled why something like this would happen.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, you could just use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). `max_u = Math.max(max_u, u)`

Comment: You should have `break;` after each `case` unless that was omitted.

Comment: @VinnyMannello but wouldn't the break be a problem since I am comparing 2 properties? Also the first property will be bigger than the smallest and smaller than the biggest and also might be either the biggest or smallest.

Comment: Can you share the dataset? At the top of my head can think of type conversion, addressing the same object, and switch optimization.

Comment: i cannot share the dataset easily i am afraid. i would like to use math.max(). problem is that the array is an array of objects from a big ajax/json response. this is happening in the success case.

Comment: What is the point of the switch(true)? I get trying new ways of doing things, but unless I'm missing something, that is making your code more complex than necessary

Comment: i am not trying new ways but didn't know better. that's why i posted this here. thanks a lot to everyone who contributed. really helped me getting to know about Math.max / min. I wasn't aware of these functions before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of objects with `u` and `p` properties (if I've read the question correctly), here's a simple function that will give you the min/max values you want and save you the problems of using `switch` and/or `if` conditions.

```
var arr = [
 { p: 10, u: 101},
 { p: 11, u: 1},
 { p: 1, u: 3},
 { p: 2, u: 7},
 { p: 21, u: 1011},
 { p: 6, u: 2},
 { p: 2, u: 13}
]

function getInt(arr, key, type) {
  return Math[type].apply(null, arr.map(function (el) {
    return el[key];
  }));
}

var min_p = getInt(arr, 'p', 'min'); // 1
var max_p = getInt(arr, 'p', 'max'); // 21
var min_u = getInt(arr, 'u', 'min'); // 1
var max_u = getInt(arr, 'u', 'max'); // 1001
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oxeh3eL2/3/)

Comment: this works. i am still baffled why the single switch didn't work.

Comment: i had to iterate through the json anyways since i am creating geometry objects from each object in the array. in the end i just pushed a parseint and parsefloat into two arrays and then directly applied Math.max / min to the arrays to get the max and min values. Thanks for your help.